# A class-IP in VPN unreachable from Docker container running in --net=host?

Tags: docker

We are running *Docker Community Edition Version 17.09.0-ce-mac35 (19611)* and trying to place the container on the same network as our Mac to reach a machine on the other side of a VPN, however starting the container with `--net=host` doesn't work the issue:

- From the machine, we are able to traceroute an ip in VPN with no hops.
- From the container, the IP is not reachable

It is noteworthy that our Docker container is using a B class private IP address while the VPN uses an A class address. Are there additional settings required to have routing configured correctly on a docker container with --net=host ?